# Msvcr90d.dll not found when building in RELEASE

Tags: c++, debugging, release, msvcr90d.dll

It's strange, if I build my program in debug mode, I have no errors, but if I build my program in released mode, I get an error saying that Msvcr90d.dll is not found.
Msvcr90d.dll is a debug library, I'm not sure why it's coming up when I load it for release =/

Answer (score 6):

msvcr90d.dll is a debug version of C/C++ library. It looks like you have a dependency somewhere on a debug target. Check that all the projects in release target use the release version of C runtime, and not the debug. Also, check other 3rd party libraries (DLLs) that you might use, so they not depend on msvcr90d.dll

You can use dependency walker tool to check the dependencies of your binaries, so you can identify the project in your solution that still depends on debug version of C library.

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting the warning LNK 4098 during build, please see this

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6wtdswk0(VS.71).aspx

And follow the recommendations.

Also, make sure that you chose the correct C/C++ runtime under the Code Generation tab (Multi-threaded DLL -- not Multithreaded Debug DLL)